# Is there a way to cut corners off a div and still use dashed border around the polygon?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I've been trying to achieve this look (see image) with a few conditions.

1. Cut off corners
2. Dashed border
3. Solid background
4. Has a drop shadow

**What I've been able to accomplish**
`clip-path` for the shape and `filter: drop-shadow` for shadow, but can't achieve the dashed border effect. I've been playing around with `repeating-linear-gradient`, but it doesn't really look that great as the image.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image: Image of button with cut off corners and dashed border]

```css
:root {
  --edge-cut-size: 15px;
  --edge-cut-negative: calc(100% - var(--edge-cut-size));
  --edge-cut-formula: polygon(var(--edge-cut-size) 0%, 
  var(--edge-cut-negative) 0%, 
  100% var(--edge-cut-size), 
  100% var(--edge-cut-negative), 
  var(--edge-cut-negative) 100%, 
  var(--edge-cut-size) 100%, 
  0% var(--edge-cut-negative), 
  0% var(--edge-cut-size));
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cut-edge {
  clip-path: var(--edge-cut-formula);
}

.shadow {
   /* Skugga */
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
}



.outer {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px;
  
  --border-width: 8px;
  --border-gap: 16px;
  
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
      90deg, 
      black 4px var(--border-width), 
      transparent 0 var(--border-gap)) var(--border-width) / calc(100% - var(--border-width)*2) calc(100%) no-repeat,
   
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      0deg, 
      black 4px var(--border-width), 
      transparent 0 var(--border-gap)) left / calc(100%) calc(100% - 20px) no-repeat;
    background-position: 30px 30px 30px 30px; 
}

.inner {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

body {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="shadow">
    <div class="outer cut-edge">
      <div class="inner cut-edge">
        Button
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @Kosh added now if that helps.

Comment: Frankly I'd just use an SVG rather than mess round with clip paths

Comment: As far as I know, that prevents me from having consistent corner cut offs though, right? @Paulie_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it with a combination of border-image and clip-path.

First, I created an image like this:
[image: Image with 4 bordered corners]

Then I created the following code snippet. A few important notes to get it working:

1. `clip-path` can only be applied to the inner element (in my case a pseudo element).
2. A negative `z-index` must be applied to make the text be displayed in front of the inner element
3. `box-shadow` can not be used, but rather `filter: drop-shadow()`

```css
:root {
  --border-size: 20px;
  --border-slice: 20;
  --clip-inner: 17px;
  --clip-displacement: 17px;
  --clip-box: calc(var(--clip-inner) * 2); /* For both sides */
  --clip-formula: polygon(
    var(--clip-inner) 0%, calc(100% - var(--clip-inner)) 0%, 
    100% var(--clip-inner), 
    100% calc(100% - var(--clip-inner)), 
    calc(100% - var(--clip-inner)) 100%, 
    var(--clip-inner) 100%, 
    0% calc(100% - var(--clip-inner)), 
    0% var(--clip-inner));
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #fff;

}

.button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: auto; 
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: var(--border-size) solid transparent;
  border-image-slice: var(--border-slice);
  border-image-repeat: round;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px rgba(0,0,0,.4));
}

.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;  
  top: calc(var(--clip-displacement) * -1 + 1px);
  left: calc(var(--clip-displacement) * -1 + 1px);  
  width: calc(100% + calc(var(--clip-displacement) * 2) - 1px);
  height: calc(100% + calc(var(--clip-displacement) * 2) - 1px); 
  clip-path: var(--clip-formula);
  z-index: -1;
}

.solid-primary {
  border-image-source: url("https://i.imgur.com/EjDAxC4.png");
  color: #111;
}

.solid-primary::after {
  background: #E772AA;
}
```

```html
<div class="button solid-primary">
  Solid primary
</div>
```